# Is there a way count all the looped boolean value in Angular html page

Tags: angular

Is there a way count all the looped boolean value in Angular html page

```
this.items = [{
    id:1,
    isUpdate: false
  },
  {
    id:2,
    isUpdate: true
  },
  {
    id:3,
    isUpdate: true
  }
```

As long as one of the isUpdate value is true, notification component will show and only show it once no matter how many isUpdate value is true.

I am wondering if there is a way to count the boolean value in app.component.html page to see if at least one of isUpdate value is true and show the notification component. And I do not want to show notification component multiple times, only show it once.

So far my code is like below, and it will show the notification multiple time:

```
app.component.html
<div *ngFor = "let notification of items">
  <notification *ngIf="notification.isUpdate"></notification>
</div>
```

and

```
Notification.component.html
<alert type="warning">
  <span class="icon-notification"></span>  Ready to update.
</alert>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write a function that will return if should show notification:

```
showNotification(): boolean {    
  this.items.forEach(item => {
    if (item.isUpdate) {
      return true;
    }
  });

  return false;
}
```

And bind it to your template:

```
<notification *ngIf="showNotification()"></notification>
```

Comment: Hi Patryk, thank you for your quick reply. In showNotification function, no matter if item.isUpdate true/false, it will always go to return false in the end.

Comment: You're welcome. If the answer is correct for your question, please mark it as resolved.

Comment: I have changed it like below, it works great. thank you again. 
 showNotification(): boolean { 
    let result:boolean = false;   
    this.items.forEach(item => {
      result = result || item.isUpdate;
    });  
    if(result) {
      return true;
    }
    else {
      return false;
    }
  }